# Как поместить один блок под другой?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Появилась задача - поместить SVG блок под блок описания, но так, чтобы он оказался ПОД блоком описания. Вот что у меня вышло:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в тексте описания есть ссылка, по которой теперь нельзя перейти, потому что блок SVG перекрывает описание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я достиг этого результата с помощью отрицательного margin, но в итоге блок SVG выше блока описания, что не дает нажать на ссылку. Как поместить блок SVG под блок описания? Спасибо! (z-index не работает!!!)

Comment: можно склонировать ссылку, сделать прозрачной и поместить поверх svg с `position: absolute` и одинаковыми параметрами top и left. или svg вставить в `background : url()`. Пока на ум приходит только это

Comment: а можно и вовсе ни делать отрицательный внешний отступ а сделать этот скос на linear-gradient или же на svg mask или clip-path,или clip-path css

Answer (score 1):

Если SVG-блок прозрачный и не интерактивный, то есть не имеет элементов управления (кнопки, ссылки и т.п.), тогда самое простое и надёжное решение добавить в CSS следующее:

```css
svg {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

При этом SVG-блок будет "прозрачен" для нажатий мыши, а следовательно будет доступ к нужной Вам ссылке и прочим элементам.